# How to get the last 60 seconds bar values of realtime data with IBrokers?

Tags: r, ibrokers

I am trying to use R package `IBrokers` to get data on different symbols. When I initially did my tests the following line worked as expected

```
reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract=contract, barSize='1 min', duration='60 S')
```

But I found out it only works when the market is closed. I need realtime data.

On the other hand the following line

```
reqRealTimeBars(tws, contract, barSize='5')
```

Provides 5 second bar values, but it streams continually and I need to query multiple instruments. I could run multiple instances of the R script but it doesn't sound right.

Does anyone have any tip on how to access the values of the last realtime 1 minute bar?

Thanks

Comment: If I use the first one while the market is open, I get intraday data.  What market are you looking at?

Comment: In this case I was trying to retrieve AAPL, here is the error I am getting waiting for TWS reply on AAPL ....failed.
`Warning message:
In errorHandler(con, verbose, OK = c(165, 300, 366, 2104, 2106,  :
  Historical Market Data Service error message:HMDS query returned no data: AAPL@SMART Trades` It does work as soon as the market closes

Comment: hmm, I got it working by changing my line to the following `reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract=contract, barSize='1 min', duration='1 D')` which makes total sense...